# Matching Older Wall Texture

Tags: walls, texture

What kind of tool and/or methods would you use to match this kind of wall texture (in attached picture)?

Based on some googling, it could be "Lace" but not sure. Trying to avoid having to even out whole walls by skim coating but have a couple of rough patches that need blending in.

[image: wall image with texture]

Comment: Stomp brush. For a patch use watery mud textured with a plastic bag. Here's a guy on YouTube doing it: youtube.com/watch?v=d0RpXfb-ex4&t=3m50s. That's the first that I found. Never heard of the guy before.

Answer (score 3):

That texture is done with a sponge.

You will need to experiment with the type of sponge and the amount of mud on the sponge to match the texture on your wall.

Most home stores have wall texture sponges in the paint sections. These are usually natural sponges.  However what was exactly used for the texture you have is unknown.

I have produced a texture like what you have in the picture with a large sponge that is usually used to wipe grout.  ( But I have used other sponges as well)

Apply a slightly thinned drywall compound to the sponge and press the sponge to the wall. DO NOT wipe. Press and remove. This will leave the peaks. How high and how close is where you will need to use trial and error.

From the pic we cannot tell the exact depth and breadth of the texture on the wall, so unfortunately you will have to experiment.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to buy a sheet of 1/4 or 3/8" drywall (around $10 currently where I live), cut it into some small sections, then practice on these small sections until the results are satisfactory. That's a lot less stress and grief than practicing on the actual wall, getting it wrong, scraping it off, and trying again...